# Selenium Drop Down Selection In https://www.goibibo.com/hotels/ website

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver, dropdown

[https://www.goibibo.com/hotels/ Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAvbV.png)

I want to select one city using selenium, but its not working
I have tried with xpath, css selector, id, className.\

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Goibibo {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver_2\\chromedriver.exe");
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
     //Goto Url Goibibo.com
     driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/hotels/");
     System.out.println("WWW.GOIBIBO.COM");
     
     //Select Country India
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='CountryType']")).click();

     System.out.println("Selected Country India");
     // Click on Search Bar
     driver.findElement(By.id("downshift-1-input")).click();

     System.out.println("Clicked On Search Bar");

     //Select Mysore City
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"downshift-1-menu\"]/div/ul/li[2]/img")).click();;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the below xpath :

```
//p[text()='Mysore']
```

or

```
//img[contains(@alt,'Mysore')]/following-sibling::div
```

in **code** :

```
System.out.println("Clicked On Search Bar");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//p[text()='Mysore']"))).click();
System.out.println("Task has been done !");
```